# Why doesn't second (sibling) React Context Provider work? Or, why doesn't a React Context Provider work if there is a sibling Context Provider above

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-context

There are routes in my react app that share data, and so I want to use Context to share data. But not all routes share the same kind of data, so my solution is to use multiple Context Providers.

```
<ClientsContextProvider>
  <ProtectedRoute
    exact
    path="/clients/:clientId"
    isAuth={isAuth}
    component={Client}
  />
  <ProtectedRoute
    exact
    path="/clients"
    isAuth={isAuth}
    component={Clients}
  />
</ClientsContextProvider>

<ProjectsContextProvider>
  <ProtectedRoute
    exact
    path="/projects"
    isAuth={isAuth}
    component={Projects}
  />
  <ProtectedRoute
    exact
    path="/projects/:projectId"
    isAuth={isAuth}
    component={Project}
  />
</ProjectsContextProvider>
```

Ultimately, the app is wrapped with an authentication context provider, but I wanted some routes to be wrapped in a specific context provider depending on the data it needs.

The current problem is that, while the routes of the top (`<ClientsContextProvider>`) work, but the sibling below it (`<ProjectsContextProvider>`) do not work. When I check the component tree with the React Developer Tools in the browser, even though I'm in the (Projects) routes, only the `<ClientsContextProvider>` is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the provider within the route:

```html
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/clients/:clientId" isAuth="{isAuth}">
  <ClientsContextProvider>
    <Clients />
  </ClientsContextProvider>
</ProtectedRoute>
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/clients" isAuth="{isAuth}">
  <ClientsContextProvider>
    <Clients />
  </ClientsContextProvider>
</ProtectedRoute>
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/projects" isAuth="{isAuth}">
  <ProjectsContextProvider>
    <Project />
  </ProjectsContextProvider>
</ProtectedRoute>
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/projects/:projectId" isAuth="{isAuth}">
  <ProjectsContextProvider>
    <Project />
  </ProjectsContextProvider>
</ProtectedRoute>
```

Comment: With this solution, will both routes be sharing the same state (i.e., both routes with the same Provider)? There won't be 2 separate context providers?

Thank you very much.